# Server Manager not available/accessible after removing .Net feature in widows server 2019

Tags: server

I have removed .Net Framework feature from "Server Manager -> Remove Roles and features Wizard".

[image]
(This image is from a different server)

Later I noticed that this activity has affected many windows features (Server manager, IIS Manager, Turn on off windows features etc..).

After removed .Net Framework feature I was not able to find the Server Manager application.

I tried answer in this [link](https://www.reddit.com/r/sysadmin/comments/ew6vbr/server_2019_how_to_reinstall_server_manager/) and able to restore ServerManager.exe but once I try to load the server manager it's giving below error,
[image]

I may be able to resolve this if I can re enable .Net frame work feature. But not sure how to do that without using server manager(since I cannot open sever manager).
Appreciate any solutions or suggestions regarding this.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Finally able to re enable .Net feature and access server manager by following below steps,

1. Open command prompt
2. Run the command: dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:NetFx4ServerFeatures /ALL and press return.
3. Type PowerShell and press enter.
4. Run the command: Install-WindowsFeature PowerShellRoot,PowerShell,PowerShell-ISE.
5. Restart the server.

Credit belongs to this blogger:
https://glennopedia.com/2020/02/14/why-you-shouldnt-remove-net-in-windows-server/

Comment: thanks a lot. I removed the .net framework in an attempt of fixing IIS registering, after reinstalling IIS, but got stucked into this ServerManager.exe removal.

Comment: Wow, thanks! Same like @FernandoJaconete mentioned happened to me, too!

Answer (score 0):

This kind of errors are caused due to lack of .NET framework on your machine or if you installed old version of framework. You need to install an appropriate .NET Framework on your computer.

Updating .NET framework on your computer will solve your problem maximum.

Install it from the [Microsoft website](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/).

Comment: Thank you Priyanka. I tried this solution but got below error when try to install .Net Framework.  ".NET Framework 4.7 or later update is already installed on this computer"

Comment: go through with this  reference https://www.majorgeeks.com/content/page/0xc0000135.html @PRTJ

Comment: Thank you Priyanka for this suggestion. But after removed .Net feature cannot access "Turn on off windows features" also so was not able to try this solution.

Answer (score 0):

dism /online /enable-feature /all /featurename:server-gui-mgmt

Answer (score -2):

Run as Administrator , the server manager will open.
Now you can try to add.